# Installing dotnet on CentOS 6.1

Tags: .net-core, redhat, centos6

Is it possible to install dotnet core sdk and runtime on CentOS 6.1?  [This site from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos) has the instructions for CentOS 7.  I downloaded the shell script to install the latest on Centos 6.1 but I get the following error below for any version that I tried.  Thanks in advance for any help.

> ./dotnet-install.sh --channel 5.0
> tput: unknown terminal "xterm-mono" dotnet-install: Attempting to
> download using primary link
> https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/5.0.408/dotnet-sdk-5.0.408-rhel.6-x64.tar.gz
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
> dotnet-install: The resource at primary link
> 'https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/5.0.408/dotnet-sdk-5.0.408-rhel.6-x64.tar.gz'
> is not available. dotnet_install: Error: Could not find `.NET Core SDK` with version = 5.0.408 dotnet_install: Error: Refer to:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-os-lifecycle for information on .NET Core
> support

Comment: Most likely it could be possible to modify it to try to download RHEL.7 version, but all bets are off if it’s actually compatible. There is also entirely manual way of downloading and “installing” so you could try that